# How to generate CSV with multi character separator like (#@#)

Tags: java, export-to-csv, apache-commons

I am using Apache Commons Csv to export the data and it has the limitation that it supports only one character as delimiter.

My requirement is to export the data using string/multi character values like `#@#`, `##`, `||` etc.

This is an example of the data I need to export:

```
 id#@#name#@#address

 1#@#user1#@#Street, country

 2#@#user2#@#"Street#@#country"
```

This is my code:

```
char delimiter = ',';
char quotechar= '"';
char escapechar= '\\';
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withDelimiter(delimiter).withQuote(quotechar).withEscape(escapechar).withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.MINIMAL); 
try {
    IPersistenceManager.OutputResource outputResource = persistenceManager.getOutputStream(resourceId + MESSAGE_SUFFIX);
    CSVPrinter writer = new CSVPrinter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputResource.Stream, Charset.defaultCharset(), csvFormat); 
    outputUri = outputResource.Uri;
    for (String[] row : dataSheet) {
        writer.printRecord(row);
    }
}
```

Can someone guide me how to achieve this using `CSVPrinter`.

Comment: If your library only takes a single char, you might replace `#@#` by a single char (`;` or something) and then proceed? Like `row.replaceAll("#@#", ";")`. It's not elegant but might be an easy solution to your problem.

Comment: Do you need to parse or to export using multi-char delimiter(s)? You mention both.

Comment: Since CSV more or less dictates that a delimiter is a single character then one can argue that this is not CSV so you might need to roll your own solution rather than using some existing library.

Comment: @mumpitz - this is not going to work in my case. values may contain delimiter in it. if i replace it will effect in value as well.. :(

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - I need to export data using multi-char delimiter.

Comment: But you are using a quote char and an escape char, how can that not work with a simple delimiter? Can you post an example of a text row that is giving you trouble?